# Pass variable which consists the name of the function to call, onclick="location.href='{% url '{{var}} ' %}'"?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to built a Port Scanner website on django.

**Problem Statement:**

What I need is the User will be selecting anyone of the radio button (full Scan or Quick Scan) and after that when the user click on `Start Now` button, that python function should be called from urls.py of views.py which the radio button holds the value of.

I saw on the internet that functions of views.py can be called using onclick="location.href='{% url ' radio value variable ' %}'" from the templates but nothing passing radiobuttons value at `url ' '`

**base.html**

```
<form id="suggestion_form" name="gs" method="get" action="home">
  <div class="searchText">
    <input type="text" name="q" class="searchText" placeholder="{% block title %} {% endblock %}" readonly="readonly">
      <ul>
        <li><label><input type="radio" name="ext_com" value="Full Scan"><span>Full Scan</span></label></li>
        <li><label><input type="radio" name="ext_com" value="Quick Scan"><span>Quick Scan</span></label></li>            
      </ul>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="results" class="main-button" value=" Start Now " onclick="location.href='{% url ' radio value variable ' %}'">
</form>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url('',views.home),
    url('',views.fullscan,name="fullscan"),
    url('',views.quickscan,name="quickscan"),
]
```

**views.py**

```
.....
def fullscan():
  If fullscan radio button is selected then this should be called an output will be rendered

def quickscan():
  If quickscan radio button is selected then this should be called an output will be rendered
```

**Solution I Tried-**

```
What I did is


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
....
<div id="search-section">
  <form id="suggestion_form" name="gs" >
  <div class="searchText" >
    <ul>
      <li><label><input type="radio" name="ext_com" data-location="{% url 'fullscan' %}" autocomplete="off" checked>Full Scan</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="radio" name="ext_com" data-location="{% url 'quickscan' %}" autocomplete="off">Quick Scan</label></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <input type="button" id="startScanBtn" name="results" class="main-button" value=" Start Now ">
   </form>
</div>
<script>
  $("#startScanBtn").on('click', function(){
    var location = $('.searchText:radio:checked').data('location');
    window.location.href=location;
    return false;
  });
</script>
....
```

Comment: What do u mean by `radio value variable`? You are supposed to pass `fullscan` or `quickscan`.

Comment: in views.py
```radio_value = request.GET.get('ext_com')```
and passing it like via render into base.html
```onclick="location.href='{% url ' {{radio_value}}' %}'"```

Comment: So, show us what you actually tried. And, *variable* from `radio value variable`?

Comment: `href='{% url radio_value %}'`

Answer (score 1):

you could use an html form or not, thats not really important there are some aother ways too.
the simplest way is to use just to  tags. which has an href attribute set to the relative url but you want to go longer walk.

```
<a href="{% url 'fullscan' %}">Full Scan</a>
<a href="{% url 'quickscan' %}">QuickScan</a>
```

or you can set onclick to the radio input itself!:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="radio" name="sname"
            id="thisId1" autocomplete="off" checked
            onclick="javascript:window.location.href({% url 'fullscan' %});">
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="sname"
            id="thisId2" autocomplete="off"
            onclick="javascript:window.location.href=`{% url 'quickscan' %}`; return false;">
    </label>
</div>
```

or even use a third button to do the location change.

```
<div class="btn-group scan-selector" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="radio" name="sname"
            id="thisId1" autocomplete="off" checked
            data-location="{% url 'fullscan' %}">
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="sname"
            id="thisId2" autocomplete="off"
            data-location="{% url 'quickscan' %}">
    </label>
</div>
<button type="button" id="startScanBtn"
>Start Now!</button>
<script>
    $("#startScanBtn").on('click', function(){
        var location = $('.scan-selecor :radio:checked').data('location');
        window.location.href=location;
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The third code seems to be what I want.
but will this make any difference?
1.firstly added this ```<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>```
2. does ```$('.scan-selector:radio:checked')``` this scan-selector refers to the scan-selector at ```<div class="btn-group scan-selector" data-toggle="buttons">``` ?
3. After doing this it shows ```http://127.0.0.1:8000/undefined``` /undefined

Comment: I have edited my Question with a solution (naming **Solution I Tried-**) referring your code snippet, could you ping me out where am I wrong.

I never tried my hands on jQuery, so..

Comment: for the comment, I think there is an space missed, before the `:` for first time it appears, but for the second time there's no space.

Comment: but I said, there is no need to jQuery. javascript is very good to do stuff in many ways